# gorm/grails sort hasMany children items

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

```
class A {
    hasMany = [b: B]
} 
class B {
    int type
    String title
    belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

Is there any way to `get` or `list` type `A`, which would have collections of type `B` sorted in one case by type, in another by title?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def listOfA = A.withCriteria {
    eq "id", 123456
    b {
        and {
            order "type", "desc"
            order "title", "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works pretty ok, but when you try to access list of `B` hibernate makes another query to get `hasMany` collection, and this query does not have the `order` param. At this point possible solution might be a `fetch "join"` parameter for `B` to fetch all data in one query. But gorm docs say it should not be used with `hasMany` relations because it does not work properly when you try to add a limit